# Using "Honoree Individual" profile for "Honoree Section" gives error on demo

Tags: profile, contributions

Doing some testing on demo. On a contribution page, checked "Honoree Section Enabled" the default profile is "Honoree Individual". But testing [the live page](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1) gives:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
API permission check failed for Contact/getoptions call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

Changing the profile to New Individual does not give the same issue. What's going on?